# How to jump to top or bottom of script with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: vim, python, ide, pycharm

I'm looking for the VI/VIM equivalent of 'gg' and 'Shift+g' but within PyCharm. Searched through their docs and didn't find anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817133/in-pycharm-how-to-navigate-to-the-top-of-the-file too

Answer (score 4):

First: Do the standard plain-text shortcuts `ctrl + home` and `ctrl + end` not work in PyCharm?

Second: If you're a Vim user, I can personally recommend IdeaVim. It's a vim emulator plugin for Idea, and google tells me that it works just as well with PyCharm.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am a mac user, so I don't have the `home` and `end` buttons. I will look into the IdeaVim option.

Comment: @Paul I haven't used a Mac in a bit, but if I'm not mistaken it should be `cmd + up arrow` and `cmd + down arrow` respectively.

Comment: That was my gut feeling but those key combos don't move the cursor around the script. Instead, they move the IDE's focus out of the script and onto PyCharm's breadcrumbs for directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X defaults in PyCharm are -

`Cmd + Fn + <UP>`: Top of the document (equivalent of `gg` in vi/m)

`Cmd + Fn + <DOWN>`: Bottom of the document (equivalent of `G` in vi/m)

Comment: @Burgi yes, they are. mac os x specific.

Comment: well I would think mention of Cmd in itself would be a clear indication; but here you go, edited anyway.

Comment: These are for the page, not the document. At least for me.

Comment: I am not sure what's the difference between page and document here? by page, do you mean visible part (on the screen) of the opened document/file?

Comment: Exactly @Shreyas

Comment: In vim, in addition to `gg` and `G` you can also type [50%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35142871/5783745) to go to the middle of a file (any other % works too)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that <kbd>Cmd+fn+left</kbd> works - it's the "Move Caret to Text Start" command. "Scroll to Top" just moves the view, but not the cursor, so as soon as you move the cursor you are back at your starting point in the code.

[image: Keymap entry]